# Name this building in Singapore and can I visit the glass pyramid on top?

Tags: architecture, identify-this, singapore

Singapore is packed with skyscrapers and iconic architecture so I guess this one just gets lost in the crowd since despite tons of Google and Wikipedia searches I can't identify it.

Its main feature of interest is a huge glass pyramid on top which looks to be quite a few stories high. At night the pyramid is lit and subtly changes colours.

I realize there are plenty of other buildings with aerial views of Singapore so I'm not looking for "Try the XYZ instead" answers. I want to know specifically the name of this particular pyramid-topped building and I want to know if it's possible to visit the pyramid part.

[image: pyramid-topped building]

[image: pyramid-topped building]

[image: pyramid-topped building]

Comment: If you can name a budget, a LOT of options jump up as dining destinations with a great view. But some of them are expensive, so you really need to say how much you are willing to spend.

Comment: @uncovery: I guess you missed the bit of my question where I specifically said `I realize there are plenty of buildings with aerial views of Singapore so I'm not looking for "Try ... instead" answers.` I just wondered about this specific building where you would be inside a giant glass pyramid as well as many stories up - that seemed pretty unique.

Comment: I assumed you simply did not want to go to the Marina Bay Sands, but others were ok.

Comment: Ah I might have to edit my question, I thought "plenty of buildings ..." was pretty clear? \-:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The building is [Millenia Tower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millenia_Tower).  It's primarily an office block building, and as far as I'm aware, there is no way to visit it.

There is a shopping center below/around it called [Millenia Walk](http://www.milleniawalk.com/) that you can visit, but I'm presuming that's not what you're looking for!

Comment: A yes I was in Millenia Walk last night and thought I might be under the "little pyramids" next to it but I wasn't sure (-:

Comment: I [found some information](http://www.e-techasia.com/latest/latest/pulsar-fixtures-illuminate-singapore-skyline) on the lighting of the pyramid, which includes one interior photo. It makes it look like the pyramid is hollow and has an open centre. I get the impression regular people are not intended to go up there. No definite answer on visiting or tours yet though.

Comment: for a brief moment I actually thought you'd asked your first question.  But no, just really quick to answer :)

Comment: @MarkMayo: Asked my first question?? What do you mean?

Comment: @hippietrail sorry not you - Doc.  He's answered hundreds but yet to ask one :)